# SimpleIoc.Default.Register fails at IsInDesignModeStatic if the Interface is in different assembly

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

In the static constructor of `ViewModelLocator` class the `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<T>();` fails at `IsInDesignModeStatic` mode, if the Interface is in a different project. As a result the `MainWindow.xaml` designer is empty at design time.

I've made a simple solution to test it. Only changes that I've made is to move the `DataItem` class and the `IDataService` interface into the Domain project.

[Download here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bwuu6nkfIcBHdUxEYmpWQ1RxWTg)

**I've found a walk-around:** Add a link to the IDataService.cs in the ClientWpf project.

```
public class ViewModelLocator {
    static ViewModelLocator() {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic) {

            // It fails if the IDataService is in different assembly
            // Delete the link of IDataService.cs from the ViewModel folder...
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: In my case, I moved the ViewModelLocator into a shared class library, to use between Wpf and Android. I completely removed the lines to register IDataService and I still had exactly the same problem. If remove the `ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic` line, the designer works fine with no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic) {


        // put these lines here:
        if (SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IDataService>()) {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<IDataService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
    }
    else {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
    }
```

Comment: I seems that when you compile your project, Visual Studio will only reload the assemblies that changed during the build. Since MvvmLight didn't changed, it keeps existing instance, including all the registered interfaces... until you restart Visual Studio.