# C# WPF Application go haywire in Release Mode but not Debug Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, release, visual-studio-debugging

From my understanding, if not mistaken, release mode should compile with more optimization and hence the size is smaller.

I'm developing a WPF C# application, when I select `Release mode`, my application goes haywired but it works fine in `Debug mode`. May I know is it even possible? What is the most common factor for this to happen?

**Update:**

By right when the application load, landing page after login will display information that retrieved from database. When in `debug mode`, the information does show as expected. But in `Release mode`, the information **does not show**.

There is no problem in Database connection because if there is, user wouldn't be able to login at all.

I'm sorry that I couldn't share any codes as the project is way too huge. I'm expecting more on a general understanding between a `Release mode` and `Debug mode` and to find out the possible cause of the situation I'm facing. Any helps would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could define "haywired" a bit more precisely please ?

Comment: @Richard: I'm sorry for the lack of information, please have a look at my updated question. Many thanks

Comment: Some places to start your diagnosis: Do you have any commandline parameters that differ between build configurations? Do you have any compilation symbols defined that differ between build configurations? Are you using lots of `#if DEBUG`? Does the target processor architecture differ between build configurations.

Answer (score 2):

The biggesdt problem here is that Debug and Release are just placeholders for a particular configuration within your projects. You can actually change what they mean project by project.

By default however the differences are actually fairly small.
[image: Debug on Left, Release on right]
[Click for large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM8mw.png)

What this means is that you can use the configuration manager (Right click Solution in the Solution Explorer) to take your Debug configuration, and create a new one based on it, and slowly change these properties over so you can find what the problem actually is.

One commonly misunderstood trick is that you can still Debug a release assembly (even after its been optimized). So you should be able to get a far better understanding of what is going on, and then ask your question again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MVVM Light there are two differents mode:

```
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainWindowViewModel>();
    }
```

[SimpleIoc.Default.Register fails at IsInDesignModeStatic if the Interface is in different assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175446/simpleioc-default-register-fails-at-isindesignmodestatic-if-the-interface-is) - there are many problems. It is not enough data to solve this problem.