# MVVMLight+MvvmDialogs The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have MVVM Light and MvvmDialogs in my WPF project.

If I have this line in ViewModelLocator's constructor

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService>(() => new DialogService(null, new DialogTypeLocator(), null));
```

I get this warning in App.xaml on this line. The designer has no binding but the application runs fine.

```
<local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
```

> There is already a factory registered for MvvmDialogs.IDialogService.

If I disable that line in design mode, then I instead get this error.

> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: These seem to be 2 totally separate issues. I removed MvvmDialogs and still have the 2nd error.

Upon further investigation, using ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic within the ViewModelLocator constructor raises the 2nd error, and registering the DialogService in design-mode raises the first error -- but then I need ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic to disable it in design mode...

Answer (score 2):

I found this post
[SimpleIoc.Default.Register fails at IsInDesignModeStatic if the Interface is in different assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175446/simpleioc-default-register-fails-at-isindesignmodestatic-if-the-interface-is-in)

I solved the first problem by registering DialogService with

```
if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IDialogService>())
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService>(() => new DialogService(null, new DialogTypeLocator(), null));
```

I "solved" the second problem by not using ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic -- that's not really a solution but at least the error is gone for now. Would love to know how set a design-time mock of the ViewModel.

Edit: A better solution for problem #1 is to add this at the beginning of the constructor

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Reset();
```

A better solution for problem #2 is to use this instead of ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic

```
DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())
```